# My headphones are making a weird static noise

Tags: windows-10, display, headphones

So all of a sudden my headphones are making a weird static noise for about 5 secs at a time and also when it happens bits of static show up on my computer. What could be the problem and how do I solve it?

Comment: "bits of static show up on my computer" - what do you mean by this? Artifacting on screen? Are your headphones wired or wireless (bluetooth)?

Comment: @spikey_richie My headphones are wired. Maybe it might be artifacting(it's just little bits of grey showing up on my screen like static)?